What to Define docBase to serve uploaded files for a virtual folder for Tomcat9 on AWS EC2 Instance with an EBS Already Mounted
I am new to linux and tomcat and am struggling as a result.  My app allows users to upload a file to the server, and then elsewhere in the app another user can view/download that uploaded file.
I am trying to configure a virtual folder path for my application running on Tomcat9 on an EC2 instance in AWS with an EBS mounted by default as a part of the free tier EC2.  Here is the definition of the storage device for the EC2
Root device name:/dev/xvda
Root device type:EBS
here are my configuration settings in server.xml in the conf folder of the apache server path.

the java code of the app is able to successfully write to the xvda/testfilefolder, however when I try to serve the file thru the browser using awsserverurl:8080/testfilename i get a page not found error.
the file path on the server when ssh in is /xvda.
What do i need to set the docBase value to so when a user accesses the file in the browser the document will load?
